# Using Params Inside a PTransform Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

I have implemented a `PTransform`:

```java
public class MyTransform extends PTransform<PCollection<I>, PCollection<T>> {

    private Object obj;


    public MyTransform(Object obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    @Override
    public PCollection<O> expand(PCollection<I> input) {

        return input.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<I, O>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                I in = c.element();
                c.output(obj.m1(in));
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

I need to use `Object` parameter inside `DoFn`. The `Object` parameter, used inside `MyTransform`, is serialized multiple times to `DoFn` function or only when it is created?

The Beam Documentation not cover the case with parameters

Answer (score 1):

`DoFn` you created is an anonymous inner class which has an implicit pointer to the enclosing class `MyTransform`. Your `DoFn` will follow that pointer and access `obj` just like a normal Java member field.

This is standard Java, which is not specific to Beam. Also, your `Object` needs to be serializable because when Beam is trying to serialize `DoFn` it will follow that pointer and try to serialize `MyTransform` and all its fields. You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032063/how-to-fix-dataflow-unable-to-serialize-my-dofn).

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification of terms, `obj` is never actually "passed" to the `DoFn` class. `obj` is initialized as a private member of the `MyTransform` class and is accessible inside the scope of the `expand` method. `MyTransform`, and therefore `obj`, are initialized once for each time `MyTransform` is serialized for execution.

So to answer your question, `obj` is "passed" to the `DoFn` class only when `MyTransform` is created. But again, this is not the correct terminology.